# Add named colors after xcolor package clash

Tags: color, option-clash

I created my LaTeX document using the `xcolor` package loaded like this

```
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
```

Now I'm trying to put the document in the journal format and I get a package clash for `xcolor` so I ended up commenting the line above. The problem now is that all the colored names I use are no longer available. Is there a way to solve this issue before digging in color names and redefining the colors?

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames}{xcolor}` should work, in my point of view

Comment: `usenames`  isn't required anymore: it is the default. But you can pass the other options, as suggested by @Christian Hupfer.